# gmail API delete not working

Tags: java, gmail, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

I'm having a little trouble with the gmail Java API. Essentially, I just reused their example code and modified it to remove all the emails that fit the query. Easy enough, but no emails are being deleted. Any ideas?

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,  new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH));

    // Allow user to authorize via url.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(SCOPE))
    .setAccessType("online")
    .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI)
            .build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type"
            + " the authorization code:\n" + url);

    // Read code entered by user.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();

    // Generate Credential using retrieved code.
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
            .setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
    .setFromTokenResponse(response);

    // Create a new authorized Gmail API client
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();

    // Retrieve a page of Threads; max of 100 by default.
    ListThreadsResponse threadsResponse = service.users().threads().list(USER).setQ("category:Promotions").execute();
    List<Thread> threads = threadsResponse.getThreads();

    // Delete each Thread.
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
              String ThreadID = thread.getId();
              service.users().threads().delete(USER, ThreadID);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to .execute() that delete operation.  :)

Comment: Bless, thank you. Knew I was missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried through the REST Client.It worked well.
Example:
If you want to delete a message you can try following end point through REST.
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/example@gmail.com/messages/14b067fa9851edc2

You will get the response 204, and your message will be deleted.